# How do we study the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n(n-1)...(n-k_n+1)}{n^{k_n}}$ wrt the relationship of $n$ and $k_n$

Tags: calculus, limits

I think that when $k_n$ is big enough the limit will be 0, and when $k_n$ is small enough the limit will be going to 1. How do we make a formal analysis?

Comment: Is $k_n$ an integer?

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same question, which I answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860040/is-it-the-case-that-frack-n-sqrtn-to-0-longrightarrow-left1-frack-n/1860055#1860055). My result implies what you are looking for in the case in which $k_n/\sqrt{n}\to0$, since $$1\geq\frac{n(n-1)\ldots(n-k_n+1)}{n^k}=\frac{n}{n}\frac{n-1}{n}\ldots\frac{n-k_n+1}{n}=\prod_{j=0}^{k_n-1}\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)\geq\left(1-\frac{k_n}{n}\right)^{k_n}.$$ I hope this helps.